# Why Realm_tgs is needed in Kerberos v5 Protocol? (Step 2)

Tags: kerberos

[image: Kerberos Message exchange]

In msg.2 the AS sends Realm_c, ID_c Ticket_tgs, K_c-tgs, times, N1, **Real_tgs**, ID_tgs encrypted with E_k_c.
I can't understand why **Real_tgs** is included if AS and TGS are on the same machine.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify your question here. Are you asking why the Realm field is required?

Comment: If I'm following your question correctly, it's because they may not actually be on the same machine, or belong to the same realm.

Comment: OK, but it is possible that for the same Kerberos Authentication Service the AS and TGS are in different Realms? What i read is that each Realm has a Kerberos server and thus different AS and TGS servers.